# floating point to int without conversion to int

Tags: c#, c

i came through this question on my interview i don't know how to solve this help me with one

"Program to truncate a given  floating point value (e.g.16.25=16). You should not assign the float value to  integer & then copy the int value to float…apply different logic."

Comment: Can you assign the float to any other data types?

Comment: no without using any other data type

Comment: convert to string, trim all chars after the decimal point.  Then you could parse the string to convert to int.

Comment: did you write "efficient use of available resources" on your résumé

Comment: This is one of those where there's not a "right" answer - the point is to get you to _think_.  So getting one solution from here would defeat that purpose :)

Comment: Wow, that's a great question. You get asked it, just walk out, save yourself all sorts of pain and difficulty.

Comment: The answer is different for various languages -- did you just randomly tag C/C# or were those actually the choices?

Comment: my skillset is in c# and they said try with c#

Comment: OK -- then you should have asked if "floating point" refers to a double or a float if we're in C# land... they are both floating point types. A double is easy -- you can just use `Math.Round`, but for a float, the answer is a bit more complex if you really can't convert it to any other types. `float f = 16.25` wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is positive:

```
#include <math.h>
printf("%f\n", floor(16.85));
```

or for positive and negative numbers:

```
printf("%f\n", trunc(16.85));
```

Comment: And if the number is negative?

Comment: @CL4PTR4P `ceil(-16.85)` of course

Comment: +1 it is interesting to know why `floor` is downvoted...

Comment: Don't you think that you should put that in the answer?

Comment: I can understand why some people downvoted this answer but I think the question is not clear enough. If an interviewer would ask me *Program to truncate a given floating point value (e.g.16.25=16).*, this would be my first answer.

Comment: I honestly downvoted simply because of the qualifier "If the number is positive." It makes it seem half an answer.

Comment: -1 removed. +1 added.

Comment: @Ouah My answer seems like the poorer cousin of yours !!

Comment: @SheerFish I +1 your answer, that's a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

See if this one will do.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

float num=16.25;
int x;
char str[10];
sprintf(str,"%f",num);
sscanf(str,"%d",&x);
printf("The number now is %d",x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you discard all the 'convert to string' type answers, and focus purely on mathematical operations, you could try this hideously inefficient process:

```
float Truncate(float n) {
  float r = 0.0
  if(n > 0.0) {
    while(n > 0.0) {
      n -= 1.0;
      r += 1.0;
    }
  } else {
    while(n < 0.0) {
      n += 1.0;
      r -= 1.0;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

It might take a hundred years to complete for larger values of N, but that's just engineering.  The algorithm is sound.  Actually, you could probably do something similar but with division rather than subtraction that would speed it up substantially.

Comment: The problem is not so much that it may take a hundred years as that it does not terminate. If `n` is `(float)(1<<26)`, then `n - 1.0f` computes as `n`.

Comment: Actually making a computer count to four billion one by one (the maximum value representable in a 32-bit `unsigned int`) takes less than a couple of minutes.